# Как реализовать покупку pro-аккаунта для приложения?

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Есть приложение, для которого существует два аккаунта: *user* и *pro*. Изначально — аккаунт *user*.

Через  *In app purchase v3* можно купить *pro*-аккаунт. Функционал приложения остаётся тот же, отличается только набор данных, которые посылаются приложению с сервера в зависимости от аккаунта.

Как лучше реализовать покупку аккаунта?

Comment: По мануалу на in app purchase. В чем проблема то?